# jQuery blur method, image instead of text

Tags: blur

I have been studying jQuery recently and wanted to try out some things on my own that the tutorial does not specify, I have searched online for it but can't find the answer. Basically I made a simple form text box and when the user focus' on the text box but doesn't type anything in and clicks somewhere else a message displays "Forgot to add text?" but i want to have an image pop up instead of just text, how would i do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljRBX.png)

$("input").blur(function(){

```
    if( $(this).val()==""){
        $(this).css('border','sold 1px red');
        $('#box').text('Forgot to add text?');
```

ps: made a small yellow box in css and inside that box is where the message displays, thats why you see the "#box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using CSS background-image?

```
   if( $(this).val()==""){
        $(this).css('border','sold 1px red');
        $('#box').css('background-image', 'url(url_to_image.jpg)'):       
        $('#box').text('Forgot to add text?');
```

But don't forget sizing and positioning. ;)

Did not try it out, but it could work.

Comment: and another way could be to give the textarea a transparent background and put an image behind it which you can show or hide via CSS `opacity` and javascript.

Comment: glad i could help :)